# How to create a HeapBuffer in Netty Java?

Tags: java, client-server, netty

I have very simple Client-Server machine implemented in Java using Netty package.
When I send some 1000 messages from Client to the Server, Netty creates a buffer with size 1024 and inserts the messages one by one into the buffer and sends to the ServerHandler(At the Server) which in turn displays the received message on to the terminal. Now the problem is when the buffer gets full the buffer is sent to the server and a new buffer is created and the remaining characters of the message are inserted into the buffer and sent again whenever the buffer is full. This makes my message string to cut off sometimes and sent to the server.

For example:

When I send "Hello Netty" from client to server a 1000 times , the buffer is filled one by one. At a particular point the buffer is full showing "Hello" as the last part inside and is sent to the server. And the remaining part "Netty" is filled into new buffer and is sent to the server. This is like sending Half strings. I want to eliminate this. I think implementing Heap Buffer in place of Unpooled.copiedBuffer(Which I implemented in the below code) can solve this situation. Is it write to do so. If so how to implement a HeapBuffer in Netty??

**ClientHandler**

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
      System.out.println("Connected");
      int i=0;
     while(i<10){
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("8=FIX.4.29=0007935=A49=TTDS68AO56=Min34=152=201704274:05:04.572108=60\n", CharsetUtil.UTF_8)); //created unpooled copiedBuffer. Need to create HeapBuffer
       i++;
    }
}
```

**ServerHandler**

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println(in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}
```

**Sample output:**(Only Showing upto 3 repetitions)

> > 8=FIX.4.29=0007935=A49=TTDS68AO56=Min34=152=201704274:05:04.572108=60 8=FIX.4.29=0007935=A49=TTDS68AO56=Min34=152=20170427-14:05:04.572108=60
> >     8=FIX.4.29=0007935=A49=TTDS68AO56=Min34=152=20170427
> >     //HALF STRING CAME HERE
> >
> > 14:05:04.572108=60     //THIS NEED TO COME ALONG WITH THE ABOVE
> >     STRING,BUT CAME AS NEW STRING

There is also a class "UnpooledHeapByteBuf" in Netty package. But I don't know how to use it. Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Tcp mss,the socket can send a data through several packets or send several datas by on packet.So you should split or combine the packet by your self.
For Example, you can add a length indicate the data size into the packet header. Of course,the Netty provide some handler to resolve it.

Let's look up following code:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("abcdefhijk", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

When you send the byte array to the other,the tcp protocol will split it into more than one packet,like this:

```
first packet:"abcdef"
second packet:"hijk"
```

One the other hand,tcp protocol also combine severals data into one packet:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("abcdefhijk", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("abcdefhijk", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

the packet is:

```
only packet:"abcdefhijkabcdefhijk"
```

So the receiver should combine these packet into a array or retrieve a array from a packet.One of useful approach is add a length indicate the array size into every packet when someone send data to another one,the length is size of the array. The `LengthFieldPrepender` handler can do that.The packet like this:

```
* +--------+----------------+
* + 0x000A | "abcdefhijk" |
* +--------+----------------+
```

The receiver should read the length from the packet header,the length is `0x000A`,and then read `0x000A` bytes of data from the packet.`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` handler can do that.

Like this:

```
@Override public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception{ ch.pipeline()..addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(204800, 0, 4, 0, 4)) .addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4)).addLast(new EchoClientHandler()); } });

@Override public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception { System.out.println("New client connected: " + ch.localAddress()); ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(204800, 0, 4, 0, 4)).addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4)).addLast(new FixMessageDecoder()); } });
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I implemented the above code in my Server program I get the following error: "io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 204800: 943539789 - discarded"

Comment: You should add this code not only server program but also client program.

Comment: No output is generating bro. Not even any exception. When I debugged it is not at all entering into the pipeline at all

Comment: Could you post server code about childHandler() and client code about handler()

Comment: Yeah sure. The following link is the entire code :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172630/how-to-retrieve-a-string-when-there-is-a-continuous-flow-of-the-messages-at-the

Comment: Bro I am getting this Exception now : io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException